# JAVA + XML + Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, java

Система такая: клиент на свинге, бд на оракле. Надо прикрутить загрузку/выгрузку в БД через xml. Подскажите плиз в какую сторону копать. На клинте или на сервере парсировать (объемы предполагаются большие). Какими механизмами парсировать, если на стороне БД?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А в чём, собственно, вопрос? Всё как обычно.. через JDBC подключаетесь к базе. Через SAX парсите XML и выполняете необходимые update'ы. Поднимаете через JDBC данные и руками или через JAXP генерируете XML.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно ли я понимаю что клиент получает данные в формате XML,
но на сервере они хранятся в базе данных?

В таком случае здесь выполняется два преобразования:

1. XML to Java Objects (POJO). Но я бы не рекомендовал вручную парсить XML с помошью SAX.IMHO удобнее описать XML с помощью XML Schema и сгенерировать на её основе классы - т.е. использовать JAXB.
2. Java Objects to Relational Database. Для этих целей прекрасно подойдет Hibernate.